# Lightweight method to order on boolean attribute in true/false/nil order

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a lightweight way of doing something like this?

```
Foo.order(:bar => [true, false, nil]).map{|f| f.bar}.uniq
=> [true, false, nil]
Foo.order(:bar => [true, false, nil]).class
=> Foo::ActiveRecord_Relation
```

The following aren't what I want:

```
Foo.order(:bar).map{|f| f.bar}.uniq
=> [false, true, nil]

Foo.order("bar DESC").map{|f| f.bar}.uniq
=> [nil, true, false]
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but you should never do `Foo.order(...).map{|f| f.bar}.uniq` when you can do `Foo.uniq.order(...).pluck(:bar)`. Don't make the database return a bunch of columns and instantiate a bunch of ActiveRecord objects when you're only going to use a single value from each row.

Comment: Jordan, wouldn't that return all uniq instances, rather than just narrow that array of 'bar' values down to a uniq set?

Comment: It will return all unique rows (it's an alias for `distinct`), and since it will only SELECT a single column, it will return the set of unique values in that column. (The query performed will essentially be `SELECT DISTINCT bar FROM foos ORDER BY ...`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
Foo.order("bar DESC NULLS LAST").map{|f| f.bar}.uniq
=> [true, false, nil]
Foo.order("bar DESC NULLS LAST").class
=> Foo::ActiveRecord_Relation
```

Comment: This is not working with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me:

```
> Foo.order(bar: :desc).map{|f| f.bar}.uniq
=> [true, false, nil]
```

I'm using ruby 2.1.5, rails 4.1.12.

Comment: What database are you using? On Postgres 9.2 thing gives me `[nil, true, false]`

Comment: MySQL. Glad you found it